# using while loop for read() in c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm a  beginner  to web developing.
i've  a  written a  code  to enter  the  serial no in to the text box.

```
OdbcConnection myOdbcConnection = new OdbcConnection(con1);

OdbcCommand myOdbcCommand = myOdbcConnection.CreateCommand();
String sSQL = "SELECT max(slno)+1 FROM driversmaster";

myOdbcCommand.CommandText = sSQL;

myOdbcConnection.Open();

OdbcDataReader myOdbcDataReader = myOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myOdbcDataReader.Read() != false)
{
    SlnoTxt.Text = myOdbcDataReader[0].ToString().Trim() ;
}
```

After  struggling  a  lot  I got  what i need. but I do not  understand  what is  the  code  that I've  written is  getting  me  the  answer. Why I'm supposed  use  a  while  loop for  read, when i can i  use "if statement"?

Please  help me  to know, so that i  will understand the  code  well.
Thanks in  advance.

Comment: have you tried out `if` ? what was the difference b/w the results from `while` and `if` ?

Comment: Look up ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader when you are interested in a single value query. Also, look up the "using" statement, learn how to properly clean up your database resources.

Comment: Without getting into your question, getting a "next value" of a serial by using `max() + 1` is really a bad practice. Think what will happen if 2 users will run this query at the same time - they will get the same serial ...

Comment: What happens when two different web users request a new serial number? They get the same number! There are big concurrency issues with this solution. You are much better off using an Oracle sequence in this case.

Comment: so can you please tel me the  better  way of geeing  a next serial number?

Comment: @SandraDsouza, you need to create a db object called `sequence` and use it like this: `select <seq_name>.nextval from dual` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm

Answer (score 1):

The result of `myOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader();` will be in database. Consider the result have 10 rows after the result of a query. `myOdbcDataReader.Read()` will only read one record at a time. So you need to put this `Read()` statement inside loop to read all records. After reading one record the pointer will automatically points next record in the database. If you are using `if` it will check weather the query returned any result or not. That is at least one record is present or not after executing the query.
 In your case I recommends to use
 `int value=(int)myOdbcCommand.ExecuteScalar();`
 since only one value is retrieved that is integer.

Comment: Thanks  for  your  help. so myOdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(); will have  the  next serial no, according to my code?

Comment: In your case after reading once the pointer will point to Null because there is no record after that. Simply use ExecuteScalar() for this purpose. This function is best for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When using the read you work through all the results that you get from your query. If you use the if-statement you will take the first result (if there is one) and be done.

So to make this short: As long as you expect only one or no result, you can use if.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, an `if` statement would work, because you are only querying one row of data.  Often when querying database data, a query could return multiple rows, in which case you would use `Read()` to advance through each row one at a time.

In your case, since you're only retrieving a single value, you may also want to consider using `ExecuteScalar()`:

```
object result = myOdbcCommand.ExecuteScalar();

SlnoTxt.Text = result.ToString();
```